# How to find sum of values of previous dates

Tags: sql-server

I have 3 columns in Invoice table.

1. InvoicePeriod
2. InvoiceType
3. Fees

I have data like this:

```
InvoicePeriod  InvoiceType  Fees
2020-06-30     ABC          10.0
2020-06-30     ABC          40.0
2020-06-30     ABC          32.0
2020-09-30     ABC          5.0
2020-09-30     XYZ          30.0
2020-12-31     ABC          20.0
2020-12-31     ABC          10.0
2021-01-31     XYZ          60.0
2021-02-01     DEF          36.0
```

Now I want the last(max) of invoice period of each invoice type and the summation of fees of previous dates.

Output:

```
InvoicePeriod  InvoiceType  Fees
2020-12-31     ABC          87.0
2021-01-31     XYZ          30.0
2021-02-01     DEF          0.0
```

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Ankit

Comment: Why the edit?  I've rolled it back. Don't link to images, if this can be avoided. Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20often%20blocked%20by,t%20useful%20to%20future%20readers.

Answer (score 1):

You want to `group by` InvoiceType (since you want one row per type) and you want the aggregate functions `max` and `sum` to combine values within those groups.

So

```
SELECT MAX(InvoicePeriod), InvoiceType, SUM(Fees)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY InvoiceType
```

Edited to exclude the fees that match the max date, now that I understand the problem better:

```
SELECT t2.MaxPeriod, t2.InvoiceType, SUM(CASE WHEN t1.InvoicePeriod < t2.MaxPeriod THEN t1.Fees ELSE 0 END)
FROM test t1 INNER JOIN
(                                              
 SELECT MAX(InvoicePeriod) MaxPeriod, InvoiceType
 FROM test
 GROUP BY InvoiceType
) t2 ON t1.InvoiceType = t2.InvoiceType
GROUP BY t2.MaxPeriod, t2.InvoiceType
```

There are different ways of doing this, but I think the above does what you want so you could build off of it. The inner query gets the max InvoicePeriod for each InvoiceType. The outer query uses that and also sums the Fees when the date is less than the max for that group.

Comment: I have written the same query but it will not give the sum of fees of previous dates.

Comment: Oh, I see. So you don't want to include the fees from the most recent date, only dates earlier?

Comment: Yes, please see the images link attached to understand the requirement and output.

Comment: I have edited my response now that I understand the requirements better.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will check the query in my system and let you know whether it is working for me or not.

Comment: Looks like the other replies (two just now) work as well, but this is the most legible. Real question is, of the three, how well do they perform?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're looking for.

```
SELECT
    MAX(in_main.InvoicePeriod) AS InvoicePeriod
    , InvoiceType
    /* Subtract out fees on last invoice date*/
    , SUM(Fees) - (
        SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Fees), 0)
        FROM Invoice in_sub
        WHERE (
            in_sub.InvoiceType = in_main.InvoiceType
            AND
            in_sub.InvoicePeriod = MAX(in_main.InvoicePeriod)
        )
    ) AS Fees
FROM Invoice in_main
GROUP BY InvoiceType
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/288adf/2/0

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Aggregate per period and type.
2. Get the sum of a type's previous periods.
3. Use `TOP WITH TIES` in combination with `ROW_NUMBER` in order to keep all types' last periods.

The query:

```
select top(1) with ties
  invoiceperiod,
  invoicetype,
  coalesce(sum(sum(fees)) over (
    partition by invoicetype
    order by invoiceperiod
    rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
  ), 0.0) as sum_fees
from invoice
group by invoiceperiod, invoicetype
order by row_number() over (partition by invoicetype order by invoiceperiod desc);
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6a651f85961b27be687026c2ce73c8f9

Comment: Thanks for your quick solution. It also takes less execution time.